# Apache Archiva backup best practices

Tags: linux, debian, backup, java

I have a server running Apache Archiva in standalone mode built from the Apache site tarball. It has been running like a charm for already 6 years. The OS is Debian Linux.

Until now all the artifacts we were storing on it where easily recoverable, so I excluded Archiva from any backup strategy.

But recently we have started to store artifacts that are impossible to rebuild. So now I need to include Archiva on my backups.

I have been googling around but I have been unable to find a clear answer on how to properly backup Archiva.

Can anyone suggest a sound procedure to create a backup of Archiva including the artifacts and the database configuration and also a procedure to restore it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation for [Apache Archiva Database](https://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.2.5/adminguide/databases.html) says that it is sufficient to backup just the user database as the artifacts are stored in the (Maven) repositories.

> While it is a good idea to back up both databases, it is not strictly
> necessary to back up the repository database on a regular basis.
> Should any data loss be suffered, this database can be regenerated by
> deleting it's contents and re-scanning the repositories.
>
> If you are using the default user security mechanism, it is important
> to back up the users database on a regular basis to ensure that the
> user passwords and information are not lost in the event of
> corruption. With the default embedded storage this is simply a matter
> of making a copy of the database directory on the filesystem. If you
> have configured an external database as the source for user
> information, please refer to your database documentation for backup
> instructions.

Backing up the artifacts is done by backing up the repositories. Archiva is just a [repository manager](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently testing this approach. When test is finished I will report the results.